# Youtube Video Player in C#

Tags: c#, youtube, visual-studio-2015

How do I embed a youtube video into my C# project?

I've looked at so many others that "answer" this question but, I can't find what I'm looking for.

I've tried many different ways to embed them but, they don't work.

I'm looking to use a web browser to just play the video but, with two options: loop and pause/play.

Reason I'm doing this is because I'm making a twitch chat bot and I'm trying to add song requests.

Latest attempt (because it was there so I decided on trying it out):

```
bool MUrlSpecify = true;
private void btnMSetCurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   const string page = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>{0}</body></html>";
     string YTUrl;
     if(MUrlSpecify == true)
     {
        YTUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + txtMSetCurrent.Text;
         wbMPlayer.DocumentText = string.Format(page, "");
     }
}
```

(MUrlSpecify is a variable I added because later I'm going to have a search function)

If anyone can tell me how I should do this I'll try their method because I'm all 
out of ideas.

Comment: What doesn't work with your current implementation? If you're able to use a built-in browser, could you not just add the browser control and direct it to the proper youtube URL?

Comment: I don't want it to show anything apart from the video and I want the options so that I can manipulate the song request via chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webbrowser.NavigateToString("player code");
Get the code from share button in youtube. Work perfectly.
Example: `wb.NavigateToString("<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dSrozYNxAA4\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");`

Comment: No I didn't. Should I?